# Stripe -> issue when configuring a customer portal through code

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am not able to update plan from the stripe customer portal(Manage billing portal) after configuring the portal through code.

```
update_to = [settings.MONTHLY_FS_PRICE_ID, price_id]  #list of price_id   
portal_config = stripe.billing_portal.Configuration.create(
            features={
                "customer_update": {
                    "allowed_updates": ["email"],
                    "enabled": True,
                },
                "invoice_history": {"enabled": True},
                "payment_method_update": {"enabled": True},
                "subscription_cancel": {
                    "enabled": cancel_enabled,
                    "mode": "immediately"
                },
                "subscription_update": {
                    "default_allowed_updates":["price", "promotion_code"],
                    "enabled": True,
                    "products": [
                        {
                            "product": product_id,
                            "prices": update_to
                        }
                    ],
                    "proration_behavior": "always_invoice"
                }
            },
            business_profile={
                "privacy_policy_url":
                    privacy_policy_url,
                "terms_of_service_url":
                    terms_url,
            },
            )
      session = stripe.billing_portal.Session.create(
        customer=request.workspace.subscription.stripeCustomerId,
        configuration=portal_config,
        return_url='http://'+settings.CURRENT_SITE_URL+'/w/dashboard'
      )
      return redirect(session.url)
```

The error in the billing portal during updating to a different plan->

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "This subscription cannot be updated to the specified pricing structure.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Updating plan works when using the default customer portal configured through no-code(i.e from the dashboard settings) but I want to configure through code for more customisation
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create

Comment: You should chat to the Stripe dev support team on their IRC channel, they are fantastic and really helpful. Just join `#stripe` on freenode. https://stripe.com/en-gb-es/contact

Comment: The code looks fine, so it's likely there's some incompatibility between the customer's subscription(s) and the price objects you're passing to the Checkout Session configuration. I'd recommend joining `#stripe` on IRC for specific help!

Comment: Thanks @TomHamiltonStubber, Jonathan.. will let you know once its resolved